# Pythonanywhere: How do I print a specific line from a text document to a textarea?

Tags: html, python-2.7, pythonanywhere

Hi I'm new to Pythonanywhere and I'm trying to print all lines with a specific word in it to a , I have had luck with printing the full document but I can't seam to get this to work.

The goal is to type in a specific word into the input form and then search for the specific in my txt file. After it has found all lines with that word it then posts it to the textarea.

Python code:

```
from flask import *
import os, sys, codecs

app = Flask(__name__)
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1')

@app.route('/search')
    def display_search():
        strWelcome = "Welcome to the website!"
        return render_template("search.html", welcome=strWelcome)

@app.route('/searching', methods=['GET','POST'])
def display_searching():
    if request.method == "POST":
        search = request.form['txt_Search']
        text_file = open(os.path.join(app.root_path, "data/logTest.txt"), "r")
    #    text_file = codecs.open(os.path.join(app.root_path, "data/logTest.txt"), "r", "latin-1", "ignore")
        all_lines = text_file.readlines()
        text_file.close()
        for line in all_lines:
            if search in line:
                log = line
        else:
            print "Sorry"
        return render_template("search.html", projTitle=strProjectHeading, pressedSubmit="True", all_lines=all_lines, log=log, search=search)
    else:
        return render_template("search.html", projTitle=strProjectHeading)
```

HTML code:

```
<label>Search for a string: </label><input name="txt_Search" type="text" id="txt_Search" title="Search"><input name="btn_Search" type="button" id="btn_Search" title="Search" value="Search" onclick="window.location.href='http://MySite.pythonanywhere.com/searching'" \>
<textarea rows="27" cols="119" name="description">{% for eachLine in log %}{{ eachLine }}{% endfor %}</textarea>
```

The page is loading and I don't see any errors in the Error Logs.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `log` to be a list, but in your code you just set it to last line you found when searching through the file.  If you put `log = []` before your for loop, and then do `log.append(line)` instead of `log = line` then that should fix that problem.  Maybe try that then report back?

Comment: Thanks bro, ill test that right now!

Comment: @GilesThomas it didn't work, I'll look into this a little more and update this page when/if I find a fix!

Answer (score 0):

There's nowhere in your template to put the search results in the page.

Comment: Sorry there is I just forgot to add the text area to the html code part